# how to make an integer variable by extracting first few array locations

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I want to ask that is there a way through which I can convert some part of int array to int variable

for example

```
   // my integer array contain 3,4,5,2,7 
    int array[] = {3,4,5 ,7,1,5,5,} ;
```

and i want a variable int to contain only first 3 member of array that is my variable should be like this

> `

```
int var = 345 ; // first three array members
```

i am using c programming
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe ?

```
int var = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var *= 10;
    var += array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean string connect?

```
char tmp[64];
sprintf(tmp, "%d%d%d", array[0], array[1], array[2]);
var = atoi(tmp);
```

Note the code above didn't check for int or buffer overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * numOfArrayElementsToConvert);
for(int i =0;i<numOfArrayElementsToConvert;i++){
   s[i] = itoa(arr[i]);
}

int var = atoi(s);
```

Comment: itoa is not a standard c lib function and it returns `char *`, you use `char *s` without initialized.